# Django admin serving uploaded image

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-file-upload, django-media

I am new to Django I'm stuck with regards to how I can fix this issue.

I have a a model which contains an ImageField as follows

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
file = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
```

and then in my settings.py I have

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

and I have the following url pattern to handle this

```
 url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
                            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes' : True
                            })
```

In the admin pages I am able to upload the image perfectly fine to the expected location in the media folder, and I am able to access this by loading 127.0.0.1:8000/media/img/my_image.jpg. The problem is that in the standard admin panel the link which shows the currently uploaded image for the object simply appends media/img/my_img.jpg to the end of the current URL and therefore receives a 404.

I am not sure what the best way to fix this issue is, I Hope this makes sense and please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

to

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

and it should stop appending to the URL and replace it instead.